# Bundle product with simple product and custom option required can't add from the reorder action

Tags: orders, bundled-product, reorder

I have issue with bundle product with simple custom option required in reorder action.When i reorder same product it always give error like `Please specify required options` as all i have debug in ordered item there is selected options.

i have also checked no other extension is conflict with this logic is it core bug or may be something going wrong with my side also nothing was changed in core code.

I am stuck with this issue still 3 days can anyone please guide me on this

Comment: i am seeing this same issue when using bundled products

Comment: Sorry @JonathanMarzullo but i didn't got any clue for this

Comment: This looks like a bug in Magento 2, and we are still waiting on a bug fix from Magento.